# How to calculate (1 - SparseMatrix) of a huge sparse matrix?

Tags: python, numpy, scipy, sparse-matrix, theano

I researched a lot on this but couldn't find a practical solution to this problem. I am using scipy to create csr sparse matrix and want to substract this matrix from an equivalent matrix of all ones. In scipy and numpy notations, if matrix is not sparse, we can do so by simply writing 1 - MatrixVariable. However, this operation is not implemented if Matrix is sparse.  I could just think of the following obvious solution:

Iterate through the entire sparse matrix, set all zero elements to 1 and all non-zero elements to 0.

But this would create a matrix where most elements are 1 and only a few are 0, which is no longer sparse and due its huge size could not be converted to dense.

What could be an alternative and effective way of doing this?

Thanks.

Comment: What do you then want to do with this `1 - matrix`? Maybe that can be achieved without creating this intermediate result.

Answer (score 1):

Your new matrix will not be sparse, because it will have `1`s everywhere, so you will need a dense array to hold it:

```
new_mat = np.ones(sps_mat.shape, sps_mat.dtype) - sps_mat.todense()
```

This requires that your matrix fits in memory. It actually requires that it fits in memory 3 times. If that is an issue, you can get it to be more efficient doing something like:

```
new_mat = sps_mat.todense()
new_mat *= -1
new_mat += 1
```

Comment: @Bhanu Well, the whole point is that your matrix is no longer going to be sparse. If you want to use this new matrix in a general setting, there is no easy way of doing it. If, on the other hand, you are looking for some specific application, then maybe there is a way around it. But without knowing what do you want it for, we cannot help.

Comment: yeah, that's true. In fact, the new matrix be just a like sparse but instead of lots of 0s it will have lots of 1's and very few 0s. I am trying to calculate pseudo_likelihood in theano's RBM, see method: "get_pseudo_likelihood_cost at [link](http://deeplearning.net/tutorial/rbm.html)

Answer (score 0):

You can access the data from your sparse matrix as a `1D array` so that:

```
ss.data *= -1
ss.data += 1
```

will work like `1 - ss`, for all non-zero elements in your sparse matrix.

Comment: Thanks, but I do need the use the values of all elements of sparse matrix. For example:   f = mean((1-ss) * vector)

Comment: But in this way your are using all elements of the sparse matrix. Using `ss.data` is one way to access and change them...